# PHP classes and functions/ undefined variable

Tags: php, function, class, undefined

Why do I get undefined property Takeover::user2 on function takeover?
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help?
I can call user2->addsaldo() on main file but I can't call it inside another function. Why?

Class user

```
class User {
/**
 * @AttributeType int
 */
private $iduser;
/**
 * @AttributeType float
 */
private $saldo=0;
/**
 * @AssociationType Portefolio
 * @AssociationKind Composition
 */
public $idportefolio;

public function __construct($iduser){
    $this->iduser = $iduser;
}

/**
 * @access public
 */
public function getid() {
    // Not yet implemented
}

/**
 * @access public
 */
public function addsaldo($saldo) {
    $this->saldo = $saldo;
}
}
```

Class takeover

```
    class Takeover {
    /**
     * @AttributeType int
     */
    private $idTakeover;
    /**
     * @AssociationType root
     * @AssociationMultiplicity 1
     */
    public $Root;

    public $IdeasTakerover=array();

    public function __construct($idTakeover){
        $this->idTakeover = $idTakeover;
    }
    /**
     * @access public
     */
    public function GetIdCompraRoot() {
        // Not yet implemented
    }

    public function AddIdeasTakeover($idTakeover, $idideia) {
        $this->idTakeover = $idTakeover;
        $this->idideia = $idideia;
        array_push($this->IdeasTakerover,$idideia);
    }
        /**
     * @access public
     */
        public function Takeover() {
            $this->user2->addsaldo(200); //USER2 DOES EXIST
    }
}
```

Creating users and calling them:

```
$takeover = new Takeover(1);

for ($i=0; $i<$conta; $i++ ){
    $takeover->AddIdeasTakeover(1,$idsideias[$i]);
}

$takeover->Takeover();

if ($partial == "user") {
            $booleanUser = TRUE;
        $iduser=substr($buffer, 4);
        ${'user'.$iduser} = new User($iduser);
}
```

Comment: Also post the classes around the code

Comment: I suggest verifying if the class was instantiated properly first, maybe by doing `var_dump($GLOBALS['user'.$this->IdeiasTakeover[$i]])`

Comment: Typo in the class name Ideia?

Comment: I tried that and: Unedefined index user and Undefined Property Takeover::$IdeiasTakeover

Comment: The class Ideia works fine :) The user class doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in this class.  The problem is that `$GLOBALS['user2']` is not defined when referenced here: `$GLOBALS['user'.$this->IdeiasTakeover[$i]]`.  You then call `addsaldo()` on an undefined array element in `$GLOBALS`.

On another note, it is impossible to write good code using `$GLOBALS`.  Global variables are bad news.  You should not be using/referencing global variables.  The exception would be at a low level when referencing $_POST, $_GET, etc.  Even still, all the good PHP frameworks wrap these in a request object.

**Edit**
Dependency Injection is a better way for one class to use another:

```
class X {

  $yInstance;

  public function __construct($yInstance)
  {
    $this->yInstance = $yInstance;
  }

  public function x()
  {
    //Call your 'y' method on an instance of Y
    $this->yInstance->y();
  }
}

class Y {
  public function y()
  {
    echo 'Y::y() called!';
  }
}
```

Call X::x()

```
$y = new Y();
$x = new X($y);
$x->x();
```

Output:

```
Y::y() called!
```

The easiest way to do this is to use a dependency injection container.  Here is my favorite one for PHP: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html

Also, check out Martin Fowlers classic article about IOC:
http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Good luck!

Comment: Ok I understand, so how can I use Y method from class Y on X method on class X? This was the only way it worked for me.

Comment: The best way it to inject class X into class Y.  I'll edit the answer to illustrate.

Comment: (if you could illustrate it for my example I would be very thankfull)

Comment: I made all that and still get undefined property, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I was demonstrating the correct way for an instance of one class to use another.  Unfortunately, in the case of your code, it should be completely rewritten.

Comment: If each Takeover instance has more than one user, I would create an instance variable and store the users in an array inside Takeover.  If there is only one user per Takeover class, I would create a 'user' instance variable and call $this->user->... in your takeover class.

Comment: I'm still using globals unfortunetly but I did that and it worked :) thank you very much